# Amidst $7$ prime numbers, difference of the largest and the smallest prime number is $d$. What is the highest possible value of $d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, contest-math

> Let $a, b, c, b+c-a, c+a-b, a+b-c$ and $a+b+c$ be $7$ distinct prime numbers. Among $a+b, b+c$ and $c+a$, only one of the three numbers is equal to $800$. If the difference of the largest prime number and the smallest prime number among the $7$ distinct prime numbers is described as $d$, then what is the highest possible value of $d$?

**SOURCE**: Bangladesh Math Olympiad

I didn't understand the pattern of rest prime numbers except $a, b$ and $c$ and their construction with the variable $a, b$ and $c$. Moreover, I couldn't catch out the probable number of the three numbers which were constructed by $a+b, b+c$ and $c+a$ whose real value is equal to $800$.

**How can I get that $7$ prime numbers by applying any method or with that condition**?

So, I really need some help and any reference to the post will be very helpful for my reaching to the conclusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There aren't many tuples a,b,c such that all the conditions are satisfied. I would suggest to get yourself a list of all the primes up to say 1000 and see whether you can find any examples for a,b,c.

Comment: The primes cannot all be $\ge5$ because then they would be $\equiv\pm1\pmod6$ and consequently one of $a+b+c,a+b-c,a-c+b,a+c-b$ would be $\equiv3\pmod 6$. Equally obviously $2$ cannot be among them for then there would be several even numbers in the collection. Therefore $3$ must be in the set.

Comment: So if your definition of *prime* includes *positive*, then we have a finite search.

Comment: @quarague I wanted to hear your verdict. Then should I waste my whole night for listing the prime numbers up to 1000?  If you see any vagueness in my text or find lack of context or any error, please don't hesitate for close voting.

Comment: Can you link to the contest page, please? So that we can ascertain that this is not an on-going contest.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry. I can't give the link. Because it is a preparatory question for the olympiad and you won't be able to understand the question as it is described in our native language.

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy There are quite a few people here, chances are someone will understand and verify.

Comment: @Macavity Then I should ascertain him that he shouldn't verify instead of keeping faith on me that I have writen the question as same as was described in that science magazine. By the way, should I delete my question? There is so much inclearity with the question.

Comment: Can you comment on whether the primes are all positive? I think that must be assumed for otherwise it is possible that the difference may become arbitrarily large (haven't checked).

Comment: Just add the link to give context. We can think of an interesting variant ourselves :-)

Comment: It is not written in that question that all of 7 discrete prime numbers must be positive. So the context is missing. But you can rather consider any of them as negative for a quite possible solution. The question has appeared neither in any olympiad nor is available in any website (I don't know even). So, I fail to provide link.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My fault. You are right. $a$ and $b$ should also be determined.

Comment: Then the only concern is that it could be an ongoing contest.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You can consider it as well. As your wish. 

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy  I didn't mean you should compute a list of the primes by hand. If you use google to help you search, this part of my suggestion takes about 10 seconds.

Comment: @quarague Okay. I will see about that. for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say $a+b=800$.

If $c\equiv  0\pmod 3$ then $c=3$ and then $a+b+c=803$ which is not a prime

If $c\equiv  1\pmod 3$ then $800+c\equiv 0\pmod 3$ so $800+c =3$ impossibile.

If $c\equiv -1\pmod 3$ then $800-c\equiv 0\pmod 3$ so $800-c =3\implies c=797$ so $a+b+c =1597$ and thus $\boxed{d= 1597-3 = 1594}$

---

Such a prime numbers exsist:

$a=787, b=13, c= 797,a+b+c=1597$

$a+b-c  =3,\;\; a+c-b= 1571$ and $b+c-a = 23$

Comment: Why? $a+b-c =3$

Comment: What primes are $a$ and $b$ then?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Right. I didn't understand even. Greedoid, would you please give some clarification?

Comment: $a=787$ and $b=13$ maybe?

Comment: @greedoid Oh! Then it was quite possible that we could tell that $a+b$ = $800$. Then where is the possibility of the condition?

Comment: @Macavity I think *isolated* is a (mis)translation of *distinct*. What do you think it means? Non-twin?

Comment: @Macavity With the condition of the above 7 prime numbers, it has been said that any of two prime numbers can't be the same.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Non twin. In the eg $13$ is twin to $11$. However, there could be other isolated solutions, so perhaps this answer is the best for now.

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy The set is symmetric under all permutations of $a,b,c$. Therefore it doesn't matter which of those three pairs sum up to $800$.

Comment: @Macavity Then there will be no solutions, as $3$ is a twin, and one of the primes must be $\pm3$.

Comment: I think Jyrki Lathonen is right. Distinction should have been applied instead of isolated number. Or Non-twin can be betterly used.

Comment: Yes, perhaps a translation issue. +1

Comment: I, too, verified $a=787, b=13, c=797$, and added my upvote.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Haha. Thank you so much for the solution. And sorry for my incapability to demonstrate the text and make it understable properly.

Comment: @greedoid Tnx for editing your answer. I have quite gotten the point and it was very helpful.